# Yii2 rest api create action return newly saved id only not saved other fields?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii2 Rest API. I am calling rest API through AJAX call from view file.
My problem is the rest API is called successfully but it's returning newly saved `id` field only not save whole information. Please see the code:

This is my JS code in View file:

```
 $url =  Url::to(Url::base().'/api/web/index.php/v1/cab/create');

  $("#submit-btn").click(function(){

    var formData = $("#form").serializeArray();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({

        url:"$url",
        type:"POST",
        data:formData,
        success:function(res){
            console.log(res);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("AJAX ERROR");
        }

    });
```

The console display only `id Object { id=23}`. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the what is returning in the method create? probably is just the id, you have to modify it if you need the whole object

Comment: Thank You for reply...i solved the issue....

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: sorry for late reply ....i changed $model->load() method parameter inside yii\rest\ActiveController - createAction $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');  to $model->load(YII::$app->getRequest()).inside Run method..  see this link for more info.. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail